# What does duration in a ROSBAG signify ?

Tags: ros

I have two ROSBAGs with almost similar data (images almost equal in number in both of them). However the duration in rosbag info shows one with 10x more than the other. I understand its the time required to play the rosbag, but what factors decide the duration of a rosbag ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In a rosbag duration is the amount of time you have in your record. Imagine you record a video stream at 10 fps during 3 minutes, you will have 3*60*10=1800 images in your bag, and duration will be 3 minutes (180 seconds). If you record a video stream at 30fps during 1 minute, you will have 30*60*1 = 1800 images, but duration will be 60 seconds.

So duration of the rosbag will reflect the time elapsed between start and stop of the record.

If the rosbag is very long, and you want to speed up reading, you can read rosbag with "-r" option. rosbag -r 2  will read foo.bag 2 times more quickly than real time.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I have created the rosbags from images with approx the same number(qty). I have not created the rosbags with diff speeds neither is the input a video stream. They have been created from a static directory of images. Do you think there could be any other reason ?

Comment: I did some more research and figured that the duration of  a rosbag is dependent on the rate at which the images were being published when it was recorded. Even if the number of images are same in number, if one ROSBAG was recorded when the images were being published at a faster rate, the duration of `rosbag play` for that rosbag will be lesser compared to the other.

Comment: I am not really sure that duration of a rosbag depend of the publish rate. According to rosbag source code : https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/lunar-devel/tools/rosbag/src/rosbag/bag.py#L635 Duration is computed by substracting the last stamp to the first stamp. How do you create your rosbag ? Do you read image in a directory, then publish them and perform a rosbag record ?